# Runestone add node to ordered linked list - error

Tags: python, linked-list

So i am following Runestone Academy online python data structure and algorithm course.

In their ordered linked list they use this code to add a node

```
def add(self,item):
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    stop = False
    while current != None and not stop:
        if current.getData() > item:
            stop = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()

    temp = Node(item)
    if previous == None:
        temp.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = temp
    else:
        temp.setNext(current)
        previous.setNext(temp)
```

Since its ordered they include the stop variable which tells the node traversal to stop when it sees a node that is bigger.

My question is that in the line:

```
   while current != None and not stop:
```

is that not wrong?

should it not be 'or' instead of 'and'?

because if it is 'and' then that means the:

```
      current!=None
```

condition also has to be met which only happens at the end of the list so even if stop is met it wont stop traversing because of that current!=None condition.

hopefully i didnt confuse too much...

Comment: No. `!=` is "not equal", so it's correct. ;) It's basically "when element exists and we're  not told to stop"

Comment: true and ture -> true, true and false-> false , true or true -> true , true or false->true, so you need and there, current!=None means that linked list is not empty and not stop s using for the condition to come out of while loop

Comment: The statement is equivalent to `while not(current == None or stop)` which might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is boolean algebra. while runs while its condition is true. `AND` is only true if both side are true, so if either `current != None` is false  OR `not stop` is false then `AND` will be false, but if you do use `OR` instead of `AND` then BOTH will need to be false for the loop to stop and that would error you out 
I recommend further reading on logic gates, specifically [AND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND))